# Creating an array/list in a mysql table and extracting it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm creating my second e-commerce store. The first store I created, I used an array to store my data. Here is an example:

```
$product = array();
$product = array();
$product[101] = array(
"category" => "Clothes",
"name" => "Caps - Stylize yours. Come in different colors.",
"img"  =>  "../img/clothes/caps/01.jpg",
"price" => 9.95,
"paypal" => "TLYMXTX7DTCHL",
"color" => array("Navy","White","Hot Pink","Yellow Cap","Navy","Black","Coral")
```

I want to be able to store the colors in my database and be able to select them in HTML so that the customer could have choices.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to save colors in a separate table using 1 to Many relation. Add productId as foreign key. After addition of product, write a for each on Colors, add in that new table.

I am sure it will be good solution for future too.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking the same, but it puzzled me because there's inventory. The productId includes the quantity, but I guess I could have it to where the administrator takes control of what is displayed in the store. Thanks!